# How to completely delete TFS backup plan

Tags: tfs

TFS backup plan has become corrupt. When I try to recreate the backup plan I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." How do I completely delete the backup plan and start from scratch? I am using TFS 2010 with Power Tools.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the tasks that are created by the TFS Management tool in the Task Scheduler in windows?

Comment: First disabling then deleting the tasks does nothing to fix the problem. I appreciate the suggestion but I'm looking for guidance on how to completely delete the backup plan and start fresh.